# Metastore db hive - another instance is already running

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to run hive on a linux server, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /home/usr/metastore_db
```

What's wrong? I tried doing:

```
ps aux | grep spark-shell
ps aux | grep metastore
ps aux | grep derby
```

But none shows any processes. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is happening as there were multiple other instances of Spark-Shell already running and holding derby DB already, so when i was starting yet another Spark Shell and creating Data Frame on it using RDD.toDF() it was throwing error:

Solution:

I ran the ps command to find other instances of Spark-Shell:

ps -ef | grep spark-shell

and i killed them all using kill command:

kill -9 Spark-Shell-processID ( example: kill -9 4848)

after all the SPark-Shell instances were gone, i started a new SPark SHell and reran my Data frame function and it ran just fine :)

Comment: I don't have any `spark-shell` process running.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with one of the below configuration on your hive-site.xml or you have not copied file at correct location for spark

avax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL

javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName

hive.metastore.uris

hive.metastore.local

hive.metastore.warehouse.dir

[hive-site.xm](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+MetastoreAdmin)